# How to get the next month of CalendarView?

Tags: android, calendarview

I am still trying to create a monthview with calendarView.

My problem is that I have no idea how I could switch the month of calendarView. I want to click a button and then the view shall display the next or last month. The view is alredy grounded, so **you cant scroll** through.

```
CalendarView cal = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarMonthView);
cal.setEnabled(false);
```

My idea is to do it with following Code:

```
long  **dateOfLastMonth** = currentMonth - month; // pseudo code
CalendarView lastMonth = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarMonthView);
lastMonth.setDate(**dateOfLastMonth**);
```

But I have no idea what value **dateOfLastMonth** should have.

Is that the right way? What value should **dateOfLastMoth** (no idea because it must be a long) have?
Is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // Calendar object, with time set to now
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1); // subtract a month
long dateOfLastMonth = cal.getTimeInMillis(); // get the milliseconds since 01/01/1970
```

If you want the 1st of the month do this

```
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
```

I suggest to do that before subtracting a month, because I don't know what happens if today is the 31st of the month and the previous month doesn't have a 31st.

**Edit:** It wouldn't be a problem if it's the 31st, I just tried it and the Calendar just sets to the 30th of the previous month

Comment: It works! But cause you cant scroll it you still see current Month. ^^